# Laravel, search query with JSON_EXTRACT and CONCAT_WS

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to perform a search inside a table containing JSON objects, but I can't figure out how to make it work with CONCAT_WS in order to search by multiple words at once, in this case, the combination of first_name & last name.

The query is working well when the search is made with a single word, (first_name, last_name, email, or phone) but does not return anything when both first_name and last_name are sent into the backend.

```
Model::whereRaw('
        JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.start") >= ?
            AND
        JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.personal") = ?
            AND 
        (
            LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.user.first_name")) LIKE ?
                OR
            LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.user.last_name")) LIKE ?
                OR
            LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.user.email")) LIKE ?
                OR
            LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.user.phone")) LIKE ?
                OR
            CONCAT_WS(" ",LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.user.first_name")),LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.user.last_name"))) LIKE ?
        )
        ', [
            Carbon::now(),
            0,
            '"%' . trim(strtolower($request->searchQuery)) . '%"',
            '"%' . trim(strtolower($request->searchQuery)) . '%"',
            '"%' . trim(strtolower($request->searchQuery)) . '%"',
            '"%' . trim(strtolower($request->searchQuery)) . '%"',
            '"%' . trim(strtolower($request->searchQuery)) . '%"',
        ])
        ->orderByRaw('JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.start") ASC')
        ->selectRaw('table.*, true AS future')
        ->get();
```

Data structure:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "data": {
            "id": 1,
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "email": "email1@email.com",
                "phone": "(000) 000-0000",
                "last_name": "John",
                "first_name": "Snow",
            },
            "start": "2022-03-24 17:00:00",
            "personal": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "data": {
            "id": 2,
            "user": {
                "id": 2,
                "email": "email2@email.com",
                "phone": "(000) 000-0000",
                "last_name": "Some",
                "first_name": "Name",
            },
            "start": "2022-03-24 17:00:00",
            "personal": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "data": {
            "id": 3,
            "user": {
                "id": 3,
                "email": "email3@email.com",
                "phone": "(000) 000-0000",
                "last_name": "Other",
                "first_name": "Name",
            },
            "start": "2022-03-24 17:00:00",
            "personal": 0
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: please share with us the testing data to test on it

Comment: @OmarTammam, I added the data structure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to edit

- replace `CONCAT_WS()` with `CONCAT()`
- use `JSON_UNQUOTE()` at `JSON_EXTRACT()` result before concating

so this line
`CONCAT_WS(" ",LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.user.first_name")),LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.user.last_name")))`

need to changes to this

```
CONCAT(
  LOWER(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data,"$.user.first_name"))),
  LOWER(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.user.last_name")))
)
```

justification
the problem was caused due to

- the use of the `trim()` method, which deletes the white spaces between the words, while you concating  `firstname` and `lastname` with spaces
- also `JSON_EXTRACT()` returns  the values with double quotes which will not cause an issue when you use like on one word, but when two words are added the quotes will exist in the middle,and the condition will be false so I used `JSON_UNQUOTE` to trim it the quotes

so you will end up with the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.start") >= '2022-03-24 03:09:08'
            AND
        JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.personal") = 0
            AND 
        (
            LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.user.first_name")) LIKE "%snowjohn%"
                OR
            LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.user.last_name")) LIKE  "%snowjohn%"
                OR
            LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.user.email")) LIKE  "%snowjohn%"
                OR
            LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.user.phone")) LIKE  "%snowjohn%"
                OR
            CONCAT(LOWER(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.user.first_name"))),LOWER(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.user.last_name"))))  LIKE  "%snowjohn%"
        );
```

Comment: did you run a test on the data structure I gave and it worked?

Comment: @c0drut i tested it right now and updated it , now it works fine

Comment: yes, this is an option and your answer did help me to find the issue. Indeed, I had to add JSON_UNQUOTE over the JSON_EXTRACT and also remove the double quotes from the last trim. Also the trim() method in not removing the white space from the middle of the search query only from the sides, so, CONCAT_WS(" ") it's working. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Great!,most welcome

Answer (score 0):

So, with the help from Omar, this is the fix for my issue!

```
Model::whereRaw('
        JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.start") >= ?
            AND
        JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.personal") = ?
            AND 
        (
            LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.user.first_name")) LIKE ?
                OR
            LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.user.last_name")) LIKE ?
                OR
            LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.user.email")) LIKE ?
                OR
            LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.user.phone")) LIKE ?
                OR
            CONCAT_WS(" ",
                LOWER(
                    JSON_UNQUOTE(
                        JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.user.first_name")
                    )
                ),
                LOWER(
                    JSON_UNQUOTE(
                        JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.user.last_name")
                    )
                )
            ) LIKE ?
        )
        ', [
            Carbon::now(),
            0,
            '"%' . trim(strtolower($request->searchQuery)) . '%"',
            '"%' . trim(strtolower($request->searchQuery)) . '%"',
            '"%' . trim(strtolower($request->searchQuery)) . '%"',
            '"%' . trim(strtolower($request->searchQuery)) . '%"',
            '%'  . trim(strtolower($request->searchQuery)) . '%',
        ])
        ->orderByRaw('JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.start") ASC')
        ->selectRaw('table.*, true AS future')
        ->get();
```